# Write a mode method in Java to find the most frequently occurring element in an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, mode

The question goes:

> Write a method called mode that returns the most frequently occurring element of an array of integers. Assume that the array has at least one element and that every element in the array has a value between 0 and 100 inclusive. Break ties by choosing the lower value.
>
> For example, if the array passed contains the values {27, 15, 15, 11, 27}, your method should return 15. (Hint: You may wish to look at the Tally program from earlier in this chapter to get an idea of how to solve this problem.)

Below is my code that almost works except for single-element arrays

```
public static int mode(int[] n)
{
    Arrays.sort(n);
    
    int count2 = 0;
    int count1 = 0;
    int pupular1 =0;
    int popular2 =0;
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++)
    {
            pupular1 = n[i];
            count1 = 0;    //see edit
        
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n.length; j++)
        {
            if (pupular1 == n[j]) count1++;
        }
        
        if (count1 > count2)
        {
                popular2 = pupular1;
                count2 = count1;
        }
        
        else if(count1 == count2)
        {
            popular2 = Math.min(popular2, pupular1);
        }
    }
    
    return popular2;
}
```

**Edit**: finally figured it out. Changed `count1 = 0;` to `count1 = 1;` everything works now!

Comment: +1 for good work before asking the question (almost works, except for single-element arrays). Could you post your solution as an answer and mark the answer correct? That way other people won't come to your question to help, thinking it has not yet been answered. Thanks.

Comment: I echo @Simon's comment and add to it that the currently-accepted answer (Gubatron's) is buggy and incorrect.  For example, it will fail on the example input `{27, 15, 15, 11, 27}`.  The length of `counts` will be 5, and the line `counts[n[I]]++` will fail because it will attempt to increment the element at index 27, which is out of bounds as shridhad notes in a comment.

Comment: I agree with Simon, would you move the solution in the edit to an answer below? We like to use the Q&A format here.

Comment: Looking back at this question almost 5 years later, I was amazed how far I have gone from then. It was the beginning of me switching career to computer science, and I had no knowledge of data structures such as `map` and `set`, etc. The almost brute force approach made me explore efficient algorithms during my study and work. it changed my life :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use a hashmap for such problems. it will take O(n) time to enter each element into the hashmap and o(1) to retrieve the element. In the given code, I am basically taking a global max and comparing it with the value received on 'get' from the hashmap, each time I am entering an element into it, have a look:

hashmap has two parts, one is the key, the second is the value when you do a get operation on the key, its value is returned.

```
public static int mode(int []array)
{
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    int max  = 1;
    int temp = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        if (hm.get(array[i]) != null) {

            int count = hm.get(array[i]);
            count++;
            hm.put(array[i], count);

            if(count > max) {
                max  = count;
                temp = array[i];
            }
        }

        else 
            hm.put(array[i],1);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: What if all the elements are unique. Are you sure we will find the result?

Comment: if all the elements are unique, there is no frequently occuring element :)

Comment: If all elements are unique, all items have a frequency of 1 and are candidates for mode. According to the question, the lowest element will be the mode.

Comment: @AbhilashKishore indeed and that's not what the code does, if there are all unique elements the mode returns ```0```, the initial temp value, to fix this you need to modify the code and add a line just before the return like this ```if(temp == 0) temp = array[(int)(Math.random() * array.length)];```. In this way a random value will get selected

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this in N operations, meaning in just one pass, O(n) time.

Use a map or int[] (if the problem is only for ints) to increment the counters, and also use a variable that keeps the key which has the max count seen. Everytime you increment a counter, ask what the value is and compare it to the key you used last, if the value is bigger update the key.

```
public class Mode {
public static int mode(final int[] n) {
    int maxKey = 0;
    int maxCounts = 0;

    int[] counts = new int[n.length];

    for (int i=0; i < n.length; i++) {
        counts[n[i]]++;
        if (maxCounts < counts[n[i]]) {
            maxCounts = counts[n[i]];
            maxKey = n[i];
        }
    }
    return maxKey;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] n = new int[] { 3,7,4,1,3,8,9,3,7,1 };
    System.out.println(mode(n));
}
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what does "counts[n[i]]++;" do ?

Comment: increments the number of ocurrences of n[i] by 1.

Comment: in case `int[] n= new int[] {12, 13, 13};` it will through `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. So this solution will work only if every number in your array is less than length of array.

Comment: Note that this is not the correct implementation of the question in which the array may contain 1-100 integers, because counts[n[i]] would overflow. Also that this is useful only in case we have boundaries around the integers.

Comment: @shridhad in addition to the example you offer, this solution will also fail on the example given in the question, namely `{27, 15, 15, 11, 27}`.

Comment: If the given values in the array are more than the array length, this will throw ArrayOutOfBounds exception.

Answer (score 2):

```
public int mode(int[] array) {
    int mode = array[0];
    int maxCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int value = array[i];
        int count = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j] == value) count++;
            if (count > maxCount) {
                mode = value;
                maxCount = count;
            }
        }
    }
    return mode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check this..
Brief:Pick each element of array and compare it with all elements of the array, weather it is equal to the picked on or not.

```
  int popularity1 = 0;
  int popularity2 = 0;
  int popularity_item, array_item; //Array contains integer value. Make it String if array contains string value.
  for(int i =0;i<array.length;i++){
      array_item = array[i];
      for(int j =0;j<array.length;j++){
          if(array_item == array[j])
             popularity1 ++;
          {
      if(popularity1 >= popularity2){
          popularity_item = array_item;
          popularity2 = popularity1;
      }
      popularity1 = 0;
  }
  //"popularity_item" contains the most repeted item in an array.
```

Comment: Try running this on an array with 1,000 random numbers.  How long does it take?  How about for an array with 1,000,000 random numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I would use this code. It includes an `instancesOf` function, and it runs through each number.

```
public class MathFunctions {

public static int mode(final int[] n) {
    int maxKey = 0;
    int maxCounts = 0;

    for (int i : n) {
        if (instancesOf(i, n) > maxCounts) {
            maxCounts = instancesOf(i, n);
            maxKey = i;
        }
    }

    return maxKey;
}

public static int instancesOf(int n, int[] Array) {
    int occurences = 0;
    for (int j : Array) {
        occurences += j == n ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return occurences;
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    //TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(mode(new int[] {100,200,2,300,300,300,500}));
}
}
```

I noticed that the code Gubatron posted doesn't work on my computer; it gave me an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: How quickly does this run on an array with 1,000,000 elements?

Comment: @phoog, really really slow.

Comment: @Cornul11 if I remember correctly, I asked that as a rhetorical question.

Comment: @phoog, hmm, rethorical affirmation then, from my part.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer.

```
public static int mode(int[] arr) {
    int max = 0;
    int maxFreq = 0;

    Arrays.sort(arr);
    max = arr[arr.length-1];

    int[] count = new int[max + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        count[arr[i]]++;
    }

     for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
        if (count[i] > maxFreq) {
            maxFreq = count[i];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
        if (count[i] == maxFreq) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: This will fail if the data in the array `arr` includes negative values.  You may also run into problems if the array includes very large values like 2,147,483,647.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is from a while ago, but I wanted to add an answer that I believe expands upon the original question. The addendum to this question was to write the mode method without relying upon a preset range (in this case, 0 through 100). I have written a version for mode that uses the range of values in the original array to generate the count array.

```
public static int mode(int[] list) {

    //Initialize max and min value variable as first value of list
    int maxValue = list[0]; 
    int minValue = list[0];

    //Finds maximum and minimum values in list
    for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i] > maxValue) {
            maxValue = list[i];
        }

        if (list[i] < minValue) {
            minValue = list[i];
        }
    }

    //Initialize count array with (maxValue - minValue + 1) elements  
    int[] count = new int[maxValue - minValue + 1];

    //Tally counts of values from list, store in array count
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        count[list[i] - minValue]++; //Increment counter index for current value of list[i] - minValue
    }

    //Find max value in count array
    int max = count[0]; //Initialize max variable as first value of count

    for (int i = 1; i < count.length; i++) {
        if (count[i] > max) {
            max = count[i];
        }
    }

    //Find first instance where max occurs in count array
    for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
        if (count[i] == max) {
            return i + minValue; //Returns index of count adjusted for min/max list values - this is the mode value in list
        }
    }
    return -1; //Only here to force compilation, never actually used
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently made a program that computes a few different stats, including mode. While the coding may be rudimentary, it works for any array of ints, and could be modified to be doubles, floats, etc. The modification to the array is based on deleting indexes in the array that are not the final mode value(s). This allows you to show all modes (if there are multiple) as well as have the amount of occurrences (last item in modes array). The code below is the getMode method as well as the deleteValueIndex method needed to run this code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public static int[] getMode(final int[] array) {           
  int[] numOfVals = new int[array.length];
  int[] valsList = new int[array.length];

  //initialize the numOfVals and valsList

  for(int ix = 0; ix < array.length; ix++) {
     valsList[ix] = array[ix];
  }

  for(int ix = 0; ix < numOfVals.length; ix++) {
     numOfVals[ix] = 1;
  }

  //freq table of items in valsList

  for(int ix = 0; ix < valsList.length - 1; ix++) {
     for(int ix2 = ix + 1; ix2 < valsList.length; ix2++) {
        if(valsList[ix2] == valsList[ix]) {
           numOfVals[ix] += 1;
        }
     }
  }

  //deletes index from valsList and numOfVals if a duplicate is found in valsList

  for(int ix = 0; ix < valsList.length - 1; ix++) {   
     for(int ix2 = ix + 1; ix2 < valsList.length; ix2++) {
        if(valsList[ix2] == valsList[ix]) {
           valsList = deleteValIndex(valsList, ix2);
           numOfVals = deleteValIndex(numOfVals, ix2);
        }
     }
  }

  //finds the highest occurence in numOfVals and sets it to most

  int most = 0;

  for(int ix = 0; ix < valsList.length; ix++) {
     if(numOfVals[ix] > most) {
        most = numOfVals[ix];
     }
  }

  //deletes index from valsList and numOfVals if corresponding index in numOfVals is less than most

  for(int ix = 0; ix < numOfVals.length; ix++) {
     if(numOfVals[ix] < most) {
        valsList = deleteValIndex(valsList, ix);
        numOfVals = deleteValIndex(numOfVals, ix);
        ix--;
     }
  }

  //sets modes equal to valsList, with the last index being most(the highest occurence)

  int[] modes = new int[valsList.length + 1];

  for(int ix = 0; ix < valsList.length; ix++) {
     modes[ix] = valsList[ix];
  }

  modes[modes.length - 1] = most;

  return modes;

}

public static int[] deleteValIndex(int[] array, final int index) {   
  int[] temp = new int[array.length - 1];
  int tempix = 0;

  //checks if index is in array

  if(index >= array.length) {
     System.out.println("I'm sorry, there are not that many items in this list.");
     return array;
  }

  //deletes index if in array

  for(int ix = 0; ix < array.length; ix++) {
     if(ix != index) {
        temp[tempix] = array[ix];
        tempix++;
     }
  }
  return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from @codemania23 and the [Java Docs for HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) I wrote this code snipped and tests of a method that **returns the most occurrent number in an array** of numbers.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Example {

    public int mostOcurrentNumber(int[] array) {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        int result = -1, max = 1;
        for (int arrayItem : array) {
            if (map.putIfAbsent(arrayItem, 1) != null) {
                int count = map.get(arrayItem) + 1;
                map.put(arrayItem, count);
                if (count > max) {
                    max = count;
                    result = arrayItem;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Unit Tests

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;

public class ExampleTest extends Example {

    @Test
    public void returnMinusOneWhenInputArrayIsEmpty() throws Exception {
        int[] array = new int[0];
        assertEquals(mostOcurrentNumber(array), -1);
    }

    @Test
    public void returnMinusOneWhenElementsUnique() {
        int[] array = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
        assertEquals(-1, mostOcurrentNumber(array));
    }

    @Test
    public void returnOne() throws Exception {
        int[] array = new int[]{0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};
        assertEquals(1, mostOcurrentNumber(array));
    }

    @Test
    public void returnFirstMostOcurrentNumber() throws Exception {
        int[] array = new int[]{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1};
        assertEquals(0, mostOcurrentNumber(array));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most fastest method around the block, but is fairly simple to understand if you don't wanna involve yourself in HashMaps and also want to avoid using 2 for loops for complexity issues....

```
    int mode(int n, int[] ar) {
    int personalMax=1,totalMax=0,maxNum=0;

    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {

        if(ar[i]==ar[i+1])
        {
            personalMax++;

            if(totalMax<personalMax)
            {
                totalMax=personalMax;
                maxNum=ar[i];
            }
        }    
        else
        {
            personalMax=1;
        }
    }
    return maxNum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have coded using single loop. We are getting mode from a[j-1] because localCount was recently updated when j was j-1. Also N is size of the array & counts are initialized to 0.

```
        //After sorting the array 
        i = 0,j=0;
        while(i!=N && j!=N){
            if(ar[i] == ar[j]){
                localCount++;
                j++;
            }
            else{
                i++;
                localCount = 0;
            }
            if(localCount > globalCount){
                globalCount = localCount;
                mode = ar[j-1]; 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    int max=0,mode=0,count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i=i+count) {
        count = 1;
        for(int j=i+1; j<N; j++) {
            if(arr[i] == arr[j])
                count++;
        }
        if(count>max) {
            max=count;
            mode = arr[i];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SmallestHighestRepeatedNumber {
    static int arr[] = { 9, 4, 5, 9, 2, 9, 1, 2, 8, 1, 1, 7, 7 };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int mode = mode(arr);
        System.out.println(mode);
    }

    public static int mode(int[] array) {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        int max = 1;
        int temp = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            if (hm.get(array[i]) != null) {

                int count = hm.get(array[i]);
                count++;
                hm.put(array[i], count);

                if (count > max || temp > array[i] && count == max) {
                    temp = array[i];
                    max = count;
                }
            } else
                hm.put(array[i], 1);
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some context?

Comment: you just copy pasted my answer dude

Answer (score -2):

THIS CODE CALCULATES MODE, MEDIAN, AND MEAN. IT IS TESTED AND IT DOES WORK. It is a complete program from start to finish and will compile.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.math.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Mason
 */
public class MODE{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.print("Enter the quantity of random numbers  ===>>  ");
        int listSize = Expo.enterInt();
        System.out.println();
        ArrayStats intStats = new ArrayStats(listSize);
        intStats.randomize();
        intStats.computeMean();
        intStats.computeMedian();
        intStats.computeMode();
        intStats.displayStats();
        System.out.println();
    }
}


class ArrayStats
{

    private int list[];
    private int size;
    private double mean;        
    private double median;      
    private int mode;           

    public ArrayStats(int s)//initializes class object
    {
        size = s;
        list = new int[size];
    }

    public void randomize()
    {
        //This will provide same numbers every time... If you want to randomize this, you can
        Random rand = new Random(555);
        for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
            list[k] = rand.nextInt(11) + 10;  
    }

    public void computeMean()
    {
               double accumulator=0;
               for (int index=0;index<size;index++)
               accumulator+= list[index];

               mean = accumulator/size;
    }

        public void computeMedian()
{
        Arrays.sort(list);
                if((size%2!=0))
                    median = list[((size-1)/2)];
                else if(size!=1&&size%2==0)
                {
                    double a =(size)/2-0.5;
                    int a2 =  (int)Math.ceil(a);
                    double b =(size)/2-0.5;
                    int b2 = (int)Math.floor(b);
                    median = (double)(list[a2]+list[b2])/2;
                }
                else if (size ==1)
                    median = list[0];
        }

    public void computeMode()
    {
 int popularity1 = 0;
  int popularity2 = 0;
  int array_item; //Array contains integer value. Make it String if array contains string value.
  for(int i =0;i<list.length;i++){
      array_item = list[i];
      for(int j =0;j<list.length;j++){
          if(array_item == list[j])
             popularity1 ++;
      }
      if(popularity1 >= popularity2){
          mode = array_item;
          popularity2 = popularity1;
      }


      popularity1 = 0;
  }}

    public void displayStats()
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Mean: " + mean);
        System.out.println("Median: " + median);
        System.out.println("Mode: " + mode);
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but your mode algorithm is very inefficient.  Did you try entering `1000000`?

Comment: nope i didn't... at least mines simple enough for the average lower level programmer to understand and implement...